# MongoDB process change stream sequentially

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have an app that allows to make donations.
I want to listen to insertion of donation records and save the total amount donated to some projection document.

Currently I do it this:

```
Donation.watch(
    [
      {
        $match: {
          operationType: 'insert',
        },
      },
    ]
  ).on('change', async data => {
    const projection = await Projection.findById(someId)
    projection.total = projection.total + data.fullDoucment.amount
    Projection.save();
  });
```

It kinda works, but there's an obvious problem: if two donations come almost at the same time, then the `projection` would still refer to the outdated version of the projection, so only one of donations would effectively be accounted for.

Is it possible to somehow process the change stream synchronously, waiting for the processing of one record to finish before starting with the next one?
Do I need to hand-roll some sort of synchronous processing queue for that? Any tips which direction to take here?

edit: apparently it's possible to use [$inc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) to build up a sum projection. But what if I needed to do something more complicated e.g. `projection.total = await someAsyncCall(projection.total, data.fullDoucment.amount)`?

Comment: You can implement a queue in your application.

Answer (score 0):

For the initial question [$inc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) works like a charm:

```
  await Projection.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
      _id: someId,
    },
    {
      $inc: { total: data.fullDoucment.amount},
    }
  );
```

For more complicated processing I'd need a serial queue or relying on mongodb versioning constraints.